# Check Cron Services in PHP

Tags: php, cron

how could I know if cron services is running using PHP script?

I want to have a PHP script that checks if cron services is running, else it will notify the admin via email so that they can make an immediate action on it.

Thank you

Comment: Is running *now* or is running according to schedule?

Comment: I want to check if services is currently running using PHP script.

Comment: many ideas here: http://serverfault.com/questions/33145/techniques-to-monitor-cron-tasks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, there are three approaches (all of which add considerable performance losses but might be acceptable for your app)

- Check process list - You can execute a console command to check the list of runniing processes. I dont think this is possible on windows but no problem on linux. Take EXTRA care to filter any and all variables used there as running console command can be a big security risk.
- running files - Create a file on start of your script and check for it's existance. I think this is how most (even non PHP) processes check if they are running. Performance loss and security issues should be minimal, you have to take care that the file is properly removed though, even in case ofa an error.
- info in storage - Like the file solution, you can add information into your database or other storage system. Performance loss is slightly bigger than file IO but if you already have a db connection for your script, it might be worth it. It's also easier to store more informatione for your current process there or add logging to it.